# telnet in php with fsockopen

Tags: php, telnet

I want to do a telnet command with fsockopen in PHP.

all i want to do in PHP is the following command in line:

```
telnet 10.72.20.94 6000
200 OK
message test
\return
```

I created a small script:

```
<?php

$ip = "10.74.20.94";
$port = 6000; 
$waitTimeoutInSeconds = 0;

$fp = fsockopen($ip,$port,$waitTimeoutInSeconds); 
$msg = "message test";

fputs($fp, $msg);   
fwrite($fp, $msg);   

fclose($fp);

?>
```

I want to send the $msg with fputs, but it does not work.

Comment: You likely need a line break.  Why use fputs and fwrite?

Comment: Great, thats it!